# Probability distribution for a noisy sine wave

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, noise

I'm looking to analytically calculate a probability distribution of sampling 
points from an oscillating function when there is some measurement error. I have
already calculated the probability distribution for the "without noise" part (I will put this at the end), but I can't figure out how to include "noise".

### Numerical estimate

To be clearer, imagine there is some function $y(x) = \sin(x)$ which you randomly pick points from during a single cycle; if you bin the points in a histogram you will get something related to the distribution.

#### Without noise

For example here is the $sin(x)$ and the corresponding histogram

[image]

#### With noise

Now if there is some measurement error then it will change the shape of the histogram (and hence I think the underlying distribution). For example

[image]

### Analytic Calculation

So hopefully I've convinced you there is some difference between the two, now I will write out how I calculated the "without noise" case:

#### Without noise

$$ y(x) = \sin(x) $$

Then if the times at which we sample are uniformly distributed then the probability distribution for $y$ must satisfy:

$$ P(y) dy = \frac{dx}{2\pi} $$

then since

$$\frac{dx}{dy} = \frac{d}{dy}\left(\arcsin(y)\right) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - y^{2}}} $$

and so

$$ P(y) = \frac{1}{2\pi\sqrt{1 - y^{2}}} $$

which with appropriate normalisation fits the histogram generated in the "no noise" case.

#### With noise

So my question is: how can I analytically include noise in the distribution? I think it is something like combining the distributions in a clever way, or including noise in the definition of $y(x)$, but I'm out of ideas and ways to move forwards so any hints/tips or even recommended reading will be much appreciated.

Comment: Jeff was correct about the 2.  Just integrated it on Wolfram Alpha, and it's P(y) = 1/(pi Sqrt(1-y^2)).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It depends on how the noise process is structured.

Assuming that I've understood your situation correctly, if the noise is additive, independent and identically distributed, you would just take the *[convolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution#Definition)* of the noise density with the density of $Y$.

If $X_i$ is random uniform over a cycle, your noiseless process conditional on $x$ is $Y_i|X_i=x_i$, which is degenerate, with mean $\sin(x_i)$ and variance 0. The marginal distribution of $Y$ is a uniform mixture of those degenerate distributions; it looks like you have worked that distribution out correctly; let's call that density $g$.

If, for example your noise is $\epsilon_i\sim N(0,\sigma^2)$, which is to say $f(\epsilon)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\,\sigma}\exp({\frac{\epsilon^2}{2\sigma^2}})$, then $f*g$ is the density of the sum of the noise with that uniform mixture of noiseless variables.

$f_{Y+\epsilon}(z) = (f*g)(z) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_{Y}(y)f_{\epsilon}(z-y)dy=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_{Y}(z-w)f_{\epsilon}(w)dw$

[image]

(this convolution was done numerically; I don't know how tractable that integral is in this example, because I didn't attempt it.)

Comment: Marvellous stuff, I was missing the idea of "convolution", as your numerics show this is spot-on. Just got to attempt the integration. Thanks

Comment: You may find it intractable, but it's usually not difficult to approximate the result numerically.

Answer (score 1):

I think the derived expression for P(x) is off by a factor of two. Uniformly distributed sample time is equivalent to uniformly distributes phase over the interval -pi,pi. The trigonometricfunction distributes probability over the y interval {-1,1}. Integrating P(y) over this interval must = 1, not 2 as obtained  using your integrand above.  I think P(y) = 1/(pi Sqrt(1-y^2))

Comment: It could well be, that was why I stated "with appropriate normalisation" as I was too lazy to think about it at the time. Thanks.